# How to create a Navigation Bar using KivyMD without kv language?

Tags: python, kivy, navigation-drawer

I want to create a navigation bar in my android application.I have searched about it a lot in google. I got the solution but it's based on kv language. I need to create without using kv language.

I don't like kivy language. I like only python

Every opinions are welcome

Many thanks in advance

Comment: So what's your problem with doing this? If you've already done it successfully with kv, there must be some specific issue preventing you adapting this to your liking?

Comment: you can write the kv code in the py file too using builderstring - if that makes the life easier

Comment: I cannot stress how wonderful the kv language is, it might be a bit daunting to learn at the start but you will catch on quickly. It will make your life much easier

Answer (score 3):

App with **[KivyMD](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD)**'s Navigation Drawer (with kv code):

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import NavigationLayout  # Do not remove

root_kv = """
<ContentNavigationDrawer@MDNavigationDrawer>:
    drawer_logo: "drawer_logo.png"

    NavigationDrawerSubheader:
        text: "Menu:"

    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
        icon: "access-point"
        text: "First"

    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
        icon: "account"
        text: "Second"


NavigationLayout:
    id: nav_layout

    ContentNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: "Toolbar title"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            background_palette: "Primary"
            background_hue: "500"
            elevation: 10
            left_action_items:
                [["menu", lambda x: app.root.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: dp(16)

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "Click me!"

            Widget:
"""


class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(root_kv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

The same app without kv code (also without bindings to app theme color, without ids and without other useful things). *(Works only with KivyMD from master branch, see [how to install](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD#how-to-install))*:

```py
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import (
    NavigationLayout,
    MDNavigationDrawer,
    NavigationDrawerSubheader,
    NavigationDrawerIconButton,
)
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        nav_layout = NavigationLayout()
        nav_drawer = MDNavigationDrawer(drawer_logo="drawer_logo.png")
        nav_drawer.add_widget(NavigationDrawerSubheader(text="Menu:"))
        nav_drawer.add_widget(
            NavigationDrawerIconButton(icon="access-point", text="First")
        )
        nav_drawer.add_widget(NavigationDrawerIconButton(icon="account", text="Second"))
        box_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        toolbar = MDToolbar(
            title="Toolbar title",
            md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
            background_palette="Primary",
            background_hue="500",
            elevation=10,
        )
        toolbar.left_action_items = [["menu", lambda x: self.root.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
        box_layout.add_widget(toolbar)
        box_layout_content = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", padding=dp(16))
        box_layout_content.add_widget(MDRaisedButton(text="Click me!"))
        box_layout_content.add_widget(Widget())
        box_layout.add_widget(box_layout_content)
        nav_layout.add_widget(nav_drawer)
        nav_layout.add_widget(box_layout)
        self.root = nav_layout


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

I think that code of app with kv language is more readable and looks nice. If you will write all your app code without kv language, it will look terrible, hard-to-edit and have many bugs later. For this reason, I advice you to learn kv language and write programs with it.