# Find an object in a library (here, it is the NavigationLayout of the Kivy library)

Tags: python, kivy

I am learning *Kivy* and I'm not used to `.kv`, so I am trying to learn the "hard way" first.

Problem: there is not a lot of documentation for interaction with *Kivy* except `.kv`.

I'm stuck with the import of the NavigationLayout, I tried to find it on the official [Github](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/kivy), but I failed !

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
#from kivy import road.to.navigationlayout import NavigationLayout


class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        main_screen = Screen()
        main_box = BoxLayout()
        main_toolbar = MDToolbar()
        main_toolbar.title = "Hello there !"
        #navigation_layout = NavigationLayout()

        screen_manager.add_widget(main_screen)
        main_screen.add_widget(main_box)
        main_box.add_widget(main_toolbar)
        return screen_manager


App().run()
```

PS: If you have tips to find out where objects are situated in new libraries, I would be happy to heard them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in the MDKivy library. (I found it with [this other stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070623/how-to-create-a-navigation-bar-using-kivymd-without-kv-language))

`from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import NavigationLayout`